# Webmin help page encoding : iso-8859-1 vs utf-8

Tags: character-encoding, webmin, xinetd

Webmin is serving static help pages.

Webmin 1.47 was using the characters set was iso-8859-1 as character encoding.  This information is transmitted by the HTTP header

```
content type:"Text/html; Charset=iso-8859-1"
```

After migration to a newer configuration using Webmin 1.81, the content type header is now utf-8 instead of the old iso-8859-1.  This difference result into a bad displaying of special characters.

```
content type:"Text/html; Charset=utf-8"
```

We are using the Xinet deamon.

I would like not to convert my oldest help pages but would rather indicates that older pages are encoded in `iso-8859-1` in their code.

Have I to convert all my help page from iso-8859-1 to utf-8? May I indicate that the encoding is `iso-8859-1` at the level of Webmin? Where is decided the encoding for the Webmin pages?

Comment: I cannot answer for webmin, but it should be relatively painless to convert your old files, see man [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's HTML, you should be able to use [meta http-equiv](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.http-equiv.content-type.html) or [meta charset](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.charset.html) to override, by putting on of these in the document's header:

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!-- or -->
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

You could also check if it's actually served by Apache (or similar); most web  servers will have a way to set the charset on a per-path basis.

but I fully expect `iconv -f latin1 -t utf8` (convert to utf8) to be a much easier solution (of course, if any of your pages already have a meta header giving the character set, you'll have to change them—`iconv` doesn't do that for you).

Comment: `iconv` by itself won't work as you suggest if the page has a `charset` already in it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey indeed, but if it already has a charset in it—then it shouldn't be getting funny characters in the browser. Nonetheless, that's a good thing to clarify.